# Easy Management of Multiple Monitor Wallpapers?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I currently use Ultramon to manage my dual monitor setup. It is nice, but what I really want is easier wallpaper switching! Yes, it can be done inside ultramon, very simple, but not simple enough. I'd love to be able to right click on an image, and have it say "Set as Left Monitors Background" or "Set as right monitors background"! Is there any program like this or am I going to have to brew my own?

Comment: Ultramo... oh, right, nevermind

Comment: I use DisplayFusion (tried Ultramon but didn't like it) and I'm annoyed by this too!

Answer (score 1):

here's a freebie:

> The [**Multi-Monitor Wallpaper
>   Tool**](http://download.cnet.com/Multi-Monitor-Wallpaper-Tool/3000-2336_4-10641534.html) allows you to easily
>   customize your desktop wallpaper for
>   dual and multi-monitor systems. Up to
>   nine images can be resized, cropped
>   and tiled as desired across any size
>   desktop image.

Comment: Can anyone vouch for this proggy?

Comment: be the first one to rate it :) however, CNET/Download.com is trustworthy enough a source.